# What laptop have you got? - Why is there no article in front of "laptop"?

Tags: grammar, articles

Laptop is a countable noun and I understand it is a general meaning here. I know it's correct to say it like this and it feels natural. But why is it so exactly? Why is there zero article?

Comment: @WS2 You mean: ***“Whose** is that laptop?”*, or better still ***“Whose** laptop is that?”*

Comment: @tchrist Sorry. My bad. I thing it was when the doorbell rang and my wife shouted "Who's that at the door".

Comment: "What" is an interrogative determiner, and since nouns can't have two determiners it is not permitted to add a further one like an article.

Comment: @WS2  Haven't you had time to delete? What does 'A preposition can replace an article with any countable noun' mean?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Exactly what it says - *the train - that train*, *a house - this house*.

Comment: @WS2 Where is the preposition in any of these? You probably mean '[demonstrative] pronoun'. But that's incorrect too: 'That train' is a determiner usage.

Answer (score 8):

*What* is a determiner in that sentence. The fact that laptop is a countable noun doesn't matter - you'd also ask *what dog do you have?*.

Articles are also determiners, and you don't generally use two determiners for the same noun (there are some exceptions, as @NigelJ mentions). So when you use *what*, you don't add an article.

For more information on determiners, see for instance [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners).

*What* (or *which*) can of course also be an interrogative pronoun, but here it is an interrogative determinatives (functioning as an interrogative  determiner). In a sentence like

> What laptop is the best laptop?

*Which* is a determiner for the first occurrence of laptop, and *the* for the second occurrence of laptop. Of course, we usually omit one of the two *laptops* in such a sentence, but the determiners remain:

> Which laptop is the best?
>   Which is the best laptop?

Comment: " you don't use two determiners for the same noun" - but (Wiki) "Determiners can also be used in certain combinations, as in my many friends or all the chairs."

Comment: @NigelJ Good point, I added a bit of nuance to that statement.

Comment: What about: *Which/what is **the** best laptop?* Or "Which of these laptop brands is [the one] used in your school?"

Comment: What or which are used as  determiners but are really  pronouns....It's considered colloquially acceptable but....

Comment: @Mari-LouA _Which/what is the best laptop?_ is short for _Which/what laptop is the best laptop?_, which shows immediately that _what/which_ is not a determiner for the second laptop.

Comment: So "what/which" are also interrogative pronouns, and I think that should  be mentioned

Comment: @Mari-LouA They are not pronouns here, but interrogative determinatives (functioning as interrogative determiners). Only relative "which/what" are pronouns.

Comment: @BillJ news to me, I've always known them as [interrogative pronouns](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/questions-interrogative-pronouns-what-who).

Comment: @BillJ I think you're wrong there, in the question "What/which is the best laptop?" doesn't "what/which" substitute "**What/which laptop** is the best laptop"? But if I ask "What laptop do you like best?" then "what" is not substituting any noun. At least that's my understanding.

Comment: @Mari-LouA In "What/which is the best laptop?", "what/which" are 'fused' determiner-heads, i.e. they simultaneously serve the function of determiner and head. But their word category (part of speech) is still interrogative determinative. Trad grammar calls them pronouns in this kind of construction, it's true, but modern grammar calls them determinatives, just as they are in "What/which laptop is the best?"

Comment: @BillJ CGEL 7.13 says that determinative _what_ does not function as fused-head, and that _what_ as head is a pronoun. The entire analysis of a separate fused-head interrogative determinative to contrast with an identical interrogative pronoun seems very iffy to me to begin with, though; I don’t see how it helps anything. They also don’t seem to mention _who_ as a comparable determinative at all, which I find odd.